# Define my own environment variables in C# project settings

Tags: c#, settings, project

I want to define my own environment variables which are used in the project settings, like $(TARGETPATH) and some predefined variables do.

How can I do this in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using this visual studio addin: http://workspacewhiz.com/SolutionBuildEnvironmentReadme.html the addin was made for Visual Studio 2008/2005/2003/2002 but might also work for 2010/2012 (havn't tested). With that addin you can set custom variables for every solution.

And for a complete list of all the existing variables: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx

Comment: So it mean we cannot define custom variable by simply modifying the csproj file, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You can try like

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MY_VARIABLE", "value", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```